# Application based Stickiness with Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tomcat, jira, gcp-load-balancer

We are in the process of migrating our on-prem environment to GCP. In our on-prem environment, we have an F5 Application Load Balancer(LB) that routes traffic to app nodes based on JSESSIONID cookie. The way it works is,

1. If the incoming request to LB doesn't have the JSESSIONID cookie then request is forwarded to one of the available app node in the pool in round robin fashion
2. If the request does have JSESSIONID, then the request is forwarded to the app node that previously set the cookie

How do I replicate this in GCP internal Load Balancer? If I set session affinity based JSESSIONID cookie, the load balancer creates a cookie before forwarding the request to the app node. This as a result causes the browser to receive two set-cookie for JSESSIONID on the response.

Comment: I can confirm this issue, I see the same behavior while deploying Jira Datacenter Helm chart into GCP.